Having issues accessing devices on subnet behind router
I have my main network with IP range 10.1.0.x, and a router connected to it with my Home Automation(HA) subnet 10.10.0.x.

Main Router IP: 10.1.0.254
HA Router IP: 10.10.0.254
HA Router Internet IP (static): 10.1.0.250

On my main network router I configured static routing:

Network Destination: 10.10.0.0/16

Gateway: 10.1.0.250 (HA Router's internet IP)

On my HA network I have a Home Assistant server with IP 10.10.0.200.

On my HA router I added multiple port forwarding entries. For example to forward port 8123 to my Home Assistant server 10.10.0.200.


From my main network I can access home assistant UI via port 8123 (configured via port forwarding on HA router).
My question is, how can I access network devices on my HA network (from main network) without port forwarding defined in the HA router?
I thought the static route entry in my main router would direct any request on my main network to 10.10.0.x to my HA router, and it would work? For example, if I try to ping 10.10.0.200 from my main network computer, it does not work? I thought the request would go to my router, and it would see there is a static route for 10.10.x.x to my HA router 10.1.0.250. It would send the packet to 10.1.0.250, and all would work.
[![Network map][2]][2]
[2]: https://i.sstatic.net/QsOSaXKn.png

so basically it depends on what kind of router "secondary router" is. if you are talking about an general-purpose or enterprise router, then you probably wouldn't be asking the question, so I'm guessing you are using a consumer-grade Internet Access router, designed to be deployed at a homes gateway to the Internet. Most IA routers won't disable the NAT wall between WAN and LAN, unless you put the router in bridge mode (which would extend the existing network to the "main network" rather than creating a new network). with the NAT in place, port forwarding is about all you can do.

to speak more directly to your question's specifics, your route will not override the NAT behavior of the device. if you are lucky your router provides the features required to disable its stateful NAT, and act as an interior router. you may have no choice but to either collapse the networks into one, or port forward service traffic from the internet network to the exterior.

Please add netmasks (/prefix lengths) to your post and diagram, otherwise the addresses alone tell me nothing.

Thanks for replies. The secondary router is a consumer grade Netgear WNR2020 router. Putting the router in bridge mode would as you mentioned just create a single network, but I want my Home Automation network to be separate(with it's own DHCP server). I did not understand what NAT between WAN and LAN was, but getting there now... Are there higher end routers that have some function like I am looking for? That will route request from my main network to devices on my Home Automation network?

so its not so much a "higher end" router as a general purpose one, but you are right, those a less available to the consumer at the standard Internet Access Router price point. there are low cost solutions like putting PFSense on a old PC you have lying around, or somesuch. One other thing you need to consider is that general purpose routers can be more complicated to configure, since they can be configured in so many ways, but most of them can be configured to simply route without too much difficulty.
